# How does cache mechanism of Orbeon 3.9 PE feature works

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I implemented the following code in all my static instances. I was expecting the browser to hold these readonly instances in client side cache but its fetching those readonly instance from server for each request.

Please confirm my understanding on **xxforms:readonly="true" xxforms:cache="true"**. If it’s wrong kindly explain the same.

```
<xforms:instance id="drop-downs" xxforms:readonly="true" xxforms:cache="true">
    <form>
        <yes-no>
            <options>Yes</options>
            <options>No</options>
        </yes-no>
        <true-false>
            <options>False</options>
            <options>True</options>
        </true-false>
    </form>
</xforms:instance>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `xxforms:readonly="true"` isn't related to caching: it is a way for you to tell Orbeon Forms that you won't be modifying data in that instance, which allows Orbeon Forms to use a more compact representation for that data, thus using less memory.
- `xxforms:cache="true"` is useful when you are retrieving the XML from a URL, not when the XML in inline in your form. In that case you can tell Orbeon that the XML at this URL is constant, and can be cached by Orbeon. This way you save yourself the cost of reading that URL every time the form is loaded.